# Left Outer Join Query returns too many rows

Tags: sql

I'm having an issue trying to get data from 4 tables.  I've tried 4 left outer joins and now i'm trying a subselect.  But as soon as I try to get the AD.AccountDirectToCommitmentItemCategoryID field, my query goes from returning the desired 4 rows to 16 rows.  I'm trying to just add that column to my results but it duplicating it each row for the each data in that column.  How should I be writing this query differently?

```
  SELECT DISTINCT  AD.AccountDirectToCommitmentItemCategoryID, cic.CommitmentItemCategoryName, cict.CommitmentItemCategoryTypeName, cic.CommitmentItemCategoryTypeID, cic.CommitmentItemCategoryID, vw.DollarsAllocated
  FROM [dbo].[tblCommitmentItemCategory] as cic
  left OUTER join [dbo].vw_ParentAccountDollarsAllocatedByCommitmentItemCategory] as vw
   on vw.CommitmentItemCategoryID = cic.CommitmentItemCategoryID
   left OUTER join [dbo].[tblCommitmentItemCategoryType] cict
   ON CIC.CommitmentItemCategoryTypeID = cict.CommitmentItemCategoryTypeID


   left OUTER join (
    SELECT DISTINCT AccountDirectToCommitmentItemCategoryID, AccountDirectParentID FROM [dbo].[tblAccountDirectToCommitmentItemCategory] ADTCIC
    WHERE ADTCIC.AccountDirectParentID = 6478) AD
   ON 
   /*(AD.AccountDirectToCommitmentItemCategoryID = VW.CommitmentItemCategoryID)   GETS 4 ROWS BUT FIRST COLUMN IS NULL */
   (AD.AccountDirectParentID = VW.AccountDirectParentID)  /*RETURNS 16 ROWS */
   where FiscalYear = 2015 and vw.AccountDirectParentID = 6478
   order by cic.CommitmentItemCategoryName
```

It wouldn't let me post an image of the results because I'm a newbie.  I hope this helps...

```
AccountDirectToCommitmentItemCategoryID CommitmentItemCategoryName  CommitmentItemCategoryTypeName  CommitmentItemCategoryTypeID    CommitmentItemCategoryID    DollarsAllocated
6   23**    Contractual 1   2   1200.00
7   23**    Contractual 1   2   1200.00
8   23**    Contractual 1   2   1200.00
9   23**    Contractual 1   2   1200.00
6   25**    Contractual 1   1   1100.00
7   25**    Contractual 1   1   1100.00
8   25**    Contractual 1   1   1100.00
9   25**    Contractual 1   1   1100.00
6   26**    Supplies    3   3   1300.00
7   26**    Supplies    3   3   1300.00
8   26**    Supplies    3   3   1300.00
9   26**    Supplies    3   3   1300.00
6   31**    Equipment   2   5   500.00
7   31**    Equipment   2   5   500.00
8   31**    Equipment   2   5   500.00
9   31**    Equipment   2   5   500.00
```

LINQ SOLUTION:  But I'm not getting a 0 Dollars row now when the is no category match:
I was able to figure out the offending column to be the parentID needing to be specfied again in the where clause.  And I created a LINQ query from it.  Unfortunately I'm not getting a 0 dollars entry when there is no matching CIC category like it used to before.  Any thoughts?

```
var queryDollars = from cic in JOHNContext.tblCommitmentItemCategory
   join vw in JOHNContext.vw_ParentAccountDollarsAllocatedByCommitmentItemCategory
        on new { CommitmentItemCategory = cic.CommitmentItemCategoryID, FiscalYear = 2015, ParentAccountID = 6478 }
            equals new { CommitmentItemCategory = vw.CommitmentItemCategoryID, FiscalYear = vw.FiscalYear, ParentAccountID = vw.AccountDirectParentID }
   into t
   from vw in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
   join cict in JOHNContext.tblCommitmentItemCategoryType
   on cic.CommitmentItemCategoryTypeID equals cict.CommitmentItemCategoryTypeID
   join ad in JOHNContext.tblAccountDirectToCommitmentItemCategory
   on vw.CommitmentItemCategoryID equals ad.CommitmentItemCategoryID
   where ad.AccountDirectParentID == 6478
   let displayCategory = cic.CommitmentItemCategoryName + " ( " + cict.CommitmentItemCategoryTypeName + " )"
// Called CategoryType but it's actually the ID below
   let displayCategoryTypeID = "CategoryType_" + ad.AccountDirectToCommitmentItemCategoryID.ToString()
//   let displayCategoryTypeID = "CategoryType_" + cic.CommitmentItemCategoryID.ToString()
   let displayDollarsAllocated = vw.DollarsAllocated == null ? 0 : vw.DollarsAllocated
   orderby cic.CommitmentItemCategoryName
   select new
   {
       displayCategory,
       displayCategoryTypeID,
       cic.CommitmentItemCategoryID,
       displayDollarsAllocated
   };
```

Comment: have you done a `select *` to see where the values are unique in the columns?  That will give you a good indication as to why your joins are producing "duplicates"

Comment: I was able to figure out the offending column to be the parentID needing to be specfied again in the where clause.  And I created a LINQ query from it.  Unfortunately I'm not getting a 0 dollars entry when there is no matching CIC category like it used to before.  Any thoughts:  Posting code in next comment I hope....

Comment: I don't see how to post the code

Comment: the `{}` button will turn your text into a code block.